# Regex Find in Files Visual Studio 2015 for Multiple Words

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2015, notepad++

I type this into VS2015 Find in Files with the Regex option button checked on but it's not returning any values:

this|that

It's working fine in Notepad++ though.

Just using VS2015 for, what seems to be, faster find in files searching.

I did it this way too:

(this|that)

With no success.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: could you give an example of your file?

Comment: It would be:

[3/19/2016 12:25:31 PM] 75.76.141.XXX:64636/7656119813829XXXX/ABC1 disconnecting: disconnect
[3/19/2016 12:25:40 PM] 96.39.137.XXX:56969/7656119811838XXXX/ABC2 disconnecting: disconnect
[3/19/2016 12:25:41 PM] 85.97.26.XXX:60301/7656119828495XXXX/ABC3 joined [windows/7656119828495XXXX]

X's there to provide some form of privacy.

75.76.141|96.39.137|85.97.26 - works fine in N++ but not in VS2015.

Comment: could you try searching something simple like `75|96` to see if regex really works? Also special characters like `.`

Comment: If I search for 75|96, it just prints anything that has the numbers 75 and 96. If I do 75.76|96.39, it prints anything that has the numbers 7576 and 9639. For example, I searched: 85.97|75.76 and got the return of: 75076, 75/76, 85597, 85697.

I'm pretty much trying to grab the IP addresses to then compare to the 76561198 number.

If there is an easier way, other than N++ is okay, then I would greatly appreciate it in finding out how.

Comment: it seems your regex `85.97|75.76` is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

It seems the regex is working fine, since searching `85.97|75.76` in the text:

```
[3/19/2016 12:25:31 PM] 75.76.141.XXX:64636/7656119813829XXXX/ABC1 disconnecting: disconnect
[3/19/2016 12:25:40 PM] 96.39.137.XXX:56969/7656119811838XXXX/ABC2 disconnecting: disconnect
[3/19/2016 12:25:41 PM] 85.97.26.XXX:60301/7656119828495XXXX/ABC3 joined
```

gives `75076`, `75/76`, `85597`, `85697`, which is a subset of what the regex is searching for.

I guess it's the implementation of VS's regex engine, that matches `.` with **anything** but not a `.` (weird enough though).

Try `\.`, it will make an escape. E.g: regex `85.97` matches with `85597`, but `85\.97` matches only with `85.97`

Comment: Doing 75\.76|85\.97 seems to work great but it's only giving me things like 75.76.ABC.DE, 75.76.FGH.IJ. Think there is something bugged with the Find in Files. I tell it to look in the root folder which is split into five more folders and I know the entries are in there but it's not pulling anything, even with Regex turned off.

Comment: @chocopie If you search for any of `75\.76|85\.97` or `75\.76` or `76|85` with regular expressions OFF then it will only match if the `\ ` or the `| ` is found.